# WPF Failed to Create an Event Handler From Text When Using a User Control Custom Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, delegates

I created a knob user control in XAML and wanted it to raise a custom event when it's value changes. I based myself off of: [Microsoft Docs Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event) and came up with the following code:

KnobControl.xaml.cs:

```cs
public static readonly RoutedEvent ValueChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ValueChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(KnobControl));

//Events
public event RoutedEventHandler ValueChanged
{
   add { AddHandler(ValueChangedEvent, value); }
   remove { RemoveHandler(ValueChangedEvent, value); }
}
```

ChannelStrip.xaml (The xaml with the control in it):

```xml
<KnobControlNamespace:KnobControl x:Name="ChannelPan" arcEndAngle="145" arcStartAngle="-145" Title="Pan" Unit="" Maximum="50" LabelFontSize="34" Step="1" Power="1" Foreground="{DynamicResource Text}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,2" Minimum="-50" ValueChanged="ChannelPan_ValueChanged"/>
```

And finally ChannelStrip.xaml.cs (This is where the event handler should be):

```cs
public void ChannelPan_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(PanEvent));
}
```

When I run this, I get: `'Failed to create a 'ValueChanged' from the text 'ChannelPan_ValueChanged'` as well as an inner exception of: `ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.`

I've spent a while now checking back at the example but I couldn't find out enough about the error to be able to debug this much myself, since I'm still fairly new to using events and WPF. I find it strange that I only get the error at this particular line since previous to implementing this custom event and event handler, other event handlers worked fine and they were identical in method signature (other than in name of course).

How should I go about trying to debug this?

Comment: Is KnobControl derived from RangeBase (the base class of e.g. the Slider control)? It already has a ValueChanged event with a different signature. As a note, it seriously looks odd that your control has properties with names that start with lowercase letters like `arcStartAngle`.

Comment: @Clemens no the KnobControl is not derived from RangeBase. The lowercase properties are due to a bit of copy paste of some unrelated code, they work fine, I just need to get around to renaming them to the correct convention ;-)

Comment: And why wouldn't you derive it from RangeBase? That would make perfect sense.

Comment: I had actually never thought of that. How would I implement this since it would no longer be derived from UserControl which provided some methods and properties I needed?

Comment: Not sure which properties you are referring to, but RangeBase already provides the Value, MinValue and MaxValue properties and the ValueChanged event. You would define the visual appearance in a ControlTemplate in a default Style. See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Comment: Alright I'll have a look into it but a few things I needed are not part of RangeBase such as: the SetValue and GetValue methods needed for using DependencyProperties and AddHandler and RemoveHandler for other events aren't available.

Comment: That's not true. It is a FrameworkElement and does of course have these methods.